# Twilio Verify not working with sendgrid when whitelist IP's used

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, verify, whitelist

Were using Sendgrid API and Twilio Verify for 2 factor authentication on our web app. Whenever we add Whitelist IP's within sendgrid our 2 factor with twilio stops working when sending via email. Iv looked online and looks like there is no specific IP to whitelist for twilio to be allowed access to send emails. Does anyone know how to do this. To clarify within sendgrid interface were adding a whitelist of IP addresses to allow email sending from these IP's

Comment: I don't think this is an issue that can be fixed on Stack Overflow. I have raised this internally at Twilio, but I also recommend that you raise a ticket with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to follow up on this.

Comment: Ya I contacted them and apparently it's not possible.